# Update main post with same category when creating custom post to update the modified date

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, hooks, publish, automatic-updates

I have 2 post type, so i create post on my main post type, then i need to create another post to fill the content to my main post in custom post type. Is there any way to update my main post publish date (modified post date) when i publish custom post type?

My main post and my custom post have the same category.

Already solved with publish_{$post->post_type} hook.
Thanks for your respond.

Comment: you can use `save_post` hook. Kindly refer to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/.

Comment: @Akshat use save_post hook and wp_update_post hook ?